# How to write to Sharepoint 2013 list using the Rest API

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, sharepoint-2013

I have been stuck for almost a week now, I want to write to a SharePoint list, usin the rest api they provide. The api looks like this, http://site/_api/lists, and from here I can read and write depending on what I append to my url, I can read from the lists without any issues, but I have issues when I have to write.

I am supposed to send in Content-Type, Accept, X-requestDigest headers, and post body when I write to list. My code

```
NSString *deviceToken = [self getDeviceTokenFromCoreData];
    NSString *postData =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ \"__metadata\": { \"type\": \"SP.Data.TestListItem\" }, \"Title\": \"Test Title\" }"];

    NSData *methodBodyData = [postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonString = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:methodBodyData options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *acceptType = @"application/json;data=verbose";
    NSString *requestDigest = _requestDigest;


    NSURL *subscribeURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:subscribeUrlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:subscribeURL];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:jsonString];
    [theRequest setValue:acceptType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [theRequest setValue:acceptType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest setValue:requestDigest forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-RequestDigest"];
```

This is where I construct my headers for the request. And this is how I handle the sending of the request

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest];

    [operation setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {
//        if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0) {

        NSLog(@"%@", challenge.protectionSpace);
            NSURLCredential *creds = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:userName
                                                                password:userPass
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

            [[challenge sender] useCredential:creds forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } else {
            [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        //Handle Success

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

       //Handle failure
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

This happens after I have authenticated to sharepoint, I have noticed during debugging the setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock never gets called again, looks like I need to send the authentication information via the headers now, which is what I think the request digest is for, but that doesnt help cause I still don't get through.

Error message I get from server is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The request digest expires every 30 minutes or so. You can get a new one by grabbing it from the response headers of any POST calls.

Comment: Can you post code on how you obtain the request digest? I get a 403 forbidden by empty body when I try to call site/_api/contextinfo

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any answer for this in internet. I solved in a non recommended way. I made a requisition using GET method to a page in the sharepoint application. In the return, i have a tag with the request digest value.
I used this in this way, in my POST requisition:

[headers setValue:@"0x175481C0D6D79A7534A0992E528A5B7D36C80C41C01CBEE55EFB256FA99E1EF551F755BAAE07E692ADE757290F1ACCA11B560F71338DE4AA7781ADC90CDC5249,11 Jun 2015 18:22:18 -0000" forKey:@"X-RequestDigest"];

Comment: But the request digest changes often, you can't hardcode it.. @thiago-rariz

Answer (score 0):

I am super new to coding so there is most likely a better way but this is how I solved this issue:

Write a method that retrieves the Request Digest from the site that looks like this:

```
-(NSDictionary *)digestValue
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://.../sites/_api/contextinfo"];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSArray* cookieArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: rtFaCookie, fedAuthCookie, nil];
NSDictionary * cookieHeaders = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookieArray];
NSMutableDictionary * requestHeaders = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: cookieHeaders];
[requestHeaders setObject: @"application/json;odata=nometadata" forKey: @"Accept"];
[requestHeaders setObject:@"application/json;odata=verbose"    forKey:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setValue:@"2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:requestHeaders];

 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSError *error;
 NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest  returningResponse:&response error:&error];
 if (data) {
 NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 return [jsonString JSONValue];
 }

 return nil;
```

}

Then call that method when you need a valid Request Digest with something like this:

```
  //Method Pulls the most current Digest Value from SharePoint, and pulls out just the Form Digest Value Key.
NSDictionary * taskMetas = [self digestValue];
NSString *formDigestValue = [taskMetas objectForKey:@"FormDigestValue"];
```